# How to read a text file and sort it by value?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

I am making a game. A players name and score are written into a text file once they finish. The text file is converted into a list. I am trying to sort it by highest score to lowest but since Sort() only sorts in alphabetical order, the values are not going in the right places. I want it to be sorted by its value instead.

```
public partial class frmLeaderboard : Form
    {

        public frmLeaderboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CenterToScreen();
            WritePlayerTextFile();
            GetPlayerHighScore();

        }

        private void frmLeaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void WritePlayerTextFile()
        {
            FileStream fs;
            if (File.Exists("playerscore.txt"))
            {
                fs = new FileStream("playerscore.txt", FileMode.Append);
            }
            else
            {
                fs = new FileStream("playerscore.txt", FileMode.Create);
            }

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine(frmRegistration.GetPlayer().GetScore() + "," + frmRegistration.GetPlayer().GetUserName());
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
private void GetPlayerHighScore()
        {

            List<string> users = File.ReadLines("playerscore.txt").ToList();
            List<string> formattedUsers = new List<string>();
            users.Sort();
            users.Reverse();

            for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] userNameScore = users[i].Split(',');
                formattedUsers.Add((i + 1) + ": " + userNameScore[1] + " Score: " + userNameScore[0]);
            }

            lstLeaderboard.DataSource = formattedUsers;
        }
```

I have tried OrderBy() but i am not familiar with it so i had no luck with it

Comment: 1. plain text is not good option, consider json file. 2. you need split convert then sort.

Comment: @LeiYang The problem with using JSON as a persisted/serialized data-store in itself is you can't make simple, append-only changes: instead you need to take an exclusive lock on the entire file, and deserialize it entirely, and then re-serialize it all, _every time_ you're saving data, for even the smallest of changes... whereas other file structures (e.g. paged rows) can support append-only writes which are much faster and can better support concurrent reads/writes depending on the use-case... and then you basically end-up with Sqlite.

Comment: i'm not sure whether OP is developing a game(if it is the case, the game will have no user), or just homework. performance is 2nd consideration i think. however, sqlite can indeed be both clean and performant. your suggest is great!

Comment: @LeiYang I cannot lie I dont really know what im doing. Im fairly new to this. I updated the code to show how the player class is implemented

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track for `OrderBy()`.

```
lstLeaderboard.OrderBy(x => x);
```

And that should sort it Alphabetically. But as this is a leaderboard you would probably want to order it by the user score. The easiest way to do that is first to convert your string into an object;

```
List<string> users = File.ReadLines("playerscore.txt").ToList();


var userObjects = users.Select(user => new { Name = user.Split(',')[1], Score = user.Split(',')[0]});
var formattedUsers = userObjects.OrderBy(user => int.Parse(user.Score))
                                .Select((user, index) => $"{index}: {user.Name} Score: {user.Score}")
                                .ToList();


lstLeaderboard.DataSource = formattedUsers;
```

Comment: 1. but you split twice, can you improve code to split only once? 2. should convert score to number then sort.

Comment: Never seen one to be happy when "score" is sorted alphabetically... But maybe OP will be the first one.

Comment: Edited my sample code hope this provides more understanding of what im trying to do.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I dont want it to be sorted alphabetically, I want it to be sorted by value.

Comment: I would parse the lines to object (with proper data types), sort it, and then use it as a datasource.